# Make Servo motors move more smoothly using a joystick?

Tags: arduino, joystick, servo

So i'm making a "turret" type thing using two servo motors, controlled by a joystick. The code i'm running works, however it's very jerky and doesn't move that well, especially in diagonal lines. My code is as follows:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#define LASER 11

int x = 0;

Servo servo_1;  // create servo object to control a servo
Servo servo_2;

// Arduino pin numbers
const int SW_pin = 2; // digital pin connected to switch output
const int X_pin = 0; // analog pin connected to X output
const int Y_pin = 1; // analog pin connected to Y output

int butt;
int joy_val;

void setup() {
  pinMode(SW_pin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(SW_pin, HIGH);
  servo_1.attach(9);// attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  servo_2.attach(10);
  pinMode(LASER, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LASER, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  joy_val = analogRead(X_pin); // reads the value of joystick (between 0-1023)
  joy_val = map(joy_val, 0, 1023, 0, 180); // servo value between 0-180
  servo_1.write(joy_val); // sets the servo position according to the joystick value
  delay(150);

  joy_val = analogRead(Y_pin); // reads the value of joystick (between 0-1023)
  joy_val = map(joy_val, 0, 1023, 0, 180); // servo value between 0-180
  servo_2.write(joy_val); // sets the servo position according to the joystick 
value
  delay(150);
  delay(15);

  butt = digitalRead(SW_pin);

  if (butt == LOW){
    x = true;
  }

  if (x == true){
    digitalWrite(LASER, LOW);
    Serial.print(x);
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate any advice or help, I'm fairly new to arduino :)

Comment: Well for a start you have a few delays in there. What happens if you remove them?

Comment: You should also explain what you mean by Jerky. I took this to mean that the input was delayed, but Adrian's answer is about smoothing out jittery joystick value readings.

Answer (score 2):

Servos are small and light and attempt to move to the position you tell them as quickly as they can.  Joysticks can also change values very quickly, and they can also be glitchy.  As a result, your servos are constantly making lots of small, quick movements, which can make the turret seem jerky.

I can think of two options, and you might want to do both:

1. Smooth out the joystick inputs with some low-pass filtering.  This generally just means using a weighted average of the current and previous values.  The idea is to eliminate a bad reading or two that might happen because of dirty contacts in the potentiometer.
2. Smooth out the motion.  Instead of instantly trying to move the servos directly to the joysticks' current positions, move them *toward* the target position.  On each iteration of the loop, they'll get closer to the target position instead of trying to jump there almost instantaneously.

For #2, there are a couple approaches I like to use.

One is to simply use a weighted average of the servo's current position and the target position.  If you move the joystick a fair distance, the turret will swivel quickly but slow down as it approaches the target position.

The other is to use a physical model.  Imagine creating a force vector that points from the servos' current position to the joysticks' target position and is proportional to the distance between them.  Apply that force to the current point.  Also apply a "friction" force that resists the current point's velocity.  Numerically integrate the velocity and the position in the loop.  If you move the joystick suddenly to a new position, then the turret will accelerate toward it and then slow down as it approaches it.  Adjusting the constants used to compute the forces will let you control how "heavy" the mechanism appears to be.

Answer (score 0):

I put a delay proportional to the speed of the servo. Try this (taken from my tutorial: [Arduino Servo Motor Basics and Control](https://makersportal.com/blog/2020/3/14/arduino-servo-motor-control)):

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <math.h>

Servo servo_1; // servo controller (multiple can exist)

int servo_pin = 3; // PWM pin for servo control
int joy_pin_x = A0; // pin for x-dir joystick
int joy_pin_y = A1; // pin for y-dir joystick
int offset_x = 0; // subtracting the initial joystick x-location
int offset_y = 0; // subtracting the initial joystick y-location
int pos = 90;    // servo starting position aligned with joystick
int prev_deg = 0; // bound for reducing jitter
int x_prev = 0; // bound for reducing jitter
int y_prev = 0; // reducing jitter

void setup() {
  servo_1.attach(servo_pin); // start servo control
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo_1.write(pos); // move to center (joystick neutral)
  Serial.println("Positioned at 90 Degrees");  
  offset_x = analogRead(joy_pin_x); // initial joystick x-val
  offset_y = analogRead(joy_pin_y); // initial joystick y-val
}

void loop() {
  int x_val = analogRead(joy_pin_x)-offset_x; // relative joystick x
  int y_val = analogRead(joy_pin_y)-offset_y; // relative joystick y
  if (abs(x_prev-x_val)<10 and abs(y_prev-y_val)<10){
    // reduce jitter
  } else {
    x_prev = x_val;
    y_prev = y_val;
    float deg = 180-(int(atan2(x_val,y_val)*(180.0/PI))+90); // angle calc
    if (abs(deg-prev_deg)>2 and deg>0 and deg<180){
      servo_1.write(deg); // move servo to joystick location
      delay(abs(deg-prev_deg)*(10.0/6.0));
      prev_deg = deg;
      Serial.println(deg); // print out degree
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the delay that is functionally dependent on the angle it's moving to - this will 'smooth' the servo and reduce jitter (though not completely remove it).